# mysql trigger signals error without telling me the actual error

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_institution AFTER UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

            UPDATE users SET institution = (SELECT name from institutes WHERE id=NEW.institute_id) WHERE id=NEW.id;

    END;
```

When I try to run this code I get a message like this :"1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5"

But what is the actual error?

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you forgot to temporarily reassign your delimiter.  Try this version:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_institution
AFTER UPDATE
    ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE users
    SET institution =
        (SELECT name from institutes WHERE id = NEW.institute_id)
    WHERE id = NEW.id;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

By reassigning the delimiter to `//` for the course of the trigger, you may continue to use semicolon without MySQL interpreting that you want the statement to end.